# what kind of interface will it be if I use Ethernet-to-USB adapter to connect raspberry pi and Jetson?

Tags: ros, serial, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may be a general question, but I want to know what type of interface will an Ethnet-to-USB connection make on both a server side and a client side. I think that on the server side, whose port is USB, it has to be a serial interface, but I'm not sure about the client side whose Ethernet will be connected. And has this connection ever been used in the ROS application? I appreciate for anybody who knows well about this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272596/what-kind-of-interface-will-it-be-if-i-use-ethernet-to-usb-adapter-to-connect-raspberry-pi-and-jetson?/) by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you referring to USB ethernet dongles? If so: that's a regular network card (NIC) as far as the OS is concerned.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on 2017-10-09**:
So then it is network-based connection, right? Not serial connection...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-09**:
Well, if your answer to my question is 'yes', then yes, it's a plain NIC, so depending on the protocols that you have configured to run over it, it would be TCP or UDP (or something else).

But definitely not serial, no.